# App Inventor's TextToSpeech does not work when the given message is too long

Tags: app-inventor

In MIT App Inventor, there is a media component called [TextToSpeech](http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/reference/components/media.html). It has a method called `Speak(text message)`, which speaks a given message.

The problem I encounter is, when the given message is very long (e.g., the text of Genesis chapter one, about 4260 characters), TextToSpeech does not speak at all. (And by the way, it works fine for Genesis chapter two, which is shorter, about 3164 characters.)

Answer (score 1):

The workaround (or solution) I have is to split the given message into a list of paragraphs by the new line character `\n`, (or into a list of sentences by the full stop character `.` if more appropriate in your case) and repeatedly call a procedure in which TextToSpeech is called to speak just a single paragraph. And in the event of TextToSpeech AfterSpeaking, check if there is more paragraph to speak; if so, call the same procedure again.

This way, every time `TextToSpeech.Speak` is called, the given message is small enough for it to work properly. Now there is no problem to speak a long message such as the text of Genesis chapter one.

See below the blocks:

[image]

**Note** on the App Inventor version I'm working with:

```
Built: November 26 2019 Version: nb180a
Use Companion: 2.55 or 2.55u or 2.55 or 2.55uu
Target Android SDK: 28 (Android 9.0 Pie)
```